# How to use device default theme for app?

Tags: android, android-theme

I have an app that I want to develop for Android 2.1, 2.2, 2.3.3, 3.0/3.1 and 4.0.x. Between those API levels, there are about 3 different types of Themes. The latest 4.0.x theme is Holo.

Anyways, I want my app to use the default Android theme for whatever device it's on. If it's on a 4.0.x device, I want it to use Holo. If it's on 2.3.3 I want it to use the theme from that version of Android. etc...

Is there a simple way to approach this? I noticed that with 4.0, they added a `Theme.DeviceDefault` theme that you can use, but this doesn't help me for older API levels. What is the best approach to this?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There are currently up to 3, sometimes 4 Themes available for Android devices (`.Light` variations and similar not included)

#### `Theme`

> [image: Theme]

the default for the earliest versions of Android up to 2.3 Gingerbread(10), including some minor style changes in those versions

---

#### `Theme.Holo`

> [image: Theme.Holo]

introduced with Android 3.0 Honeycomb (11)

---

#### `Theme.Material`

> [image: Theme.Material]

new in Android 5.0 Lollipop (21)

---

#### `Theme.DeviceDefault`

> (Could be anything)

introduced with 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich (14), a theme that can be customized by the device manufacturer. It represents the native look of the device - i.e. Holo or Material on Nexus devices (& in Android Studio's design editor), maybe something custom on other devices. In case "something custom" isn't an option, those devices must come with the stock themes. Apps that want the stock theme have to specify it though.

---

> What is the best approach to this?

#### No theme + targetSdkVersion >= 14

The simplest, but not necessarily best option is to define no theme at all. Android will then select the default for you. But Android does not want to surprise your app with themes you're not expecting so it falls back to the Theme you probably had designed your app for. It does so by looking at the `android:targetSdkVersion` within `AndroidManifest.xml` (which can nowadays be set via gradle).

- Apps that target old platforms, which had only `Theme` (i.e. API levels 3-10), will get only `Theme`.
- Apps targeting 11-13 get `Theme.Holo`.
- 14 or above will get `Theme.DeviceDefault`.

Since this is just for backwards compatibility, you won't get `Theme.Material` on your old Gingerbread phone. Therefore no theme + target 14+ = device default.

#### Specifying different themes

Android's resource overlay system allows to specify styles based on device API level. For example different versions of a style in `res/values-v11` and `res/values-v21`. This is also what any newly created apps via Android Studio will setup for you.

As an example, the most basic setup for a `.Light` themed app looks like this:

`/res/values/styles.xml` is applied to every device and serves as base

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"/>
</resources>
```

---

`/res/values-v11/styles.xml` is loaded on all devices that have API level 11 and above (including those that are 21 and above). But just the newest version of "AppTheme" is actually used.

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"/>
</resources>
```

---

`/res/values-v21/styles.xml`

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light"/>
</resources>
```

Note: alternatively specifying `Theme.DeviceDefault` in `/res/values-v14/styles.xml` should be enough for having a default look but that doesn't allow to fine tune the design. Doesn't hurt to add the v14 override. DeviceDefault and Holo could be different after all.

---

`AndroidManifest.xml` is the place where the custom theme is put to use. E.g. as application wide default:

```
...
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    ...
```

---

#### Links to official documentation

[Select a theme based on platform version](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#SelectATheme) - Official doc for defining different styles via resource configurations

[Holo Everywhere](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html) - blog post that explains the default mechanism and DeviceDefault / Holo theme

[Using the Material Theme](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) - material documentation

Comment: I will need to experiment with this a bit. If I set the `targetSdkVersion="11"`, how will that affect devices that run my app on 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3.3 (API Levels 7, 8, and 9/10)? I guess I'm a little confused on the difference between a target API level and a minimum API level.

Comment: `targetSdkVersion` indicates compatibility up to a certain API level. If your app runs on a higher API device then some compatibility options are enabled and the devices behaves like the highest level you specify. If the device is lower than your target level then it just behaves like it does. The minimum level is what level your app requires to run - devices below don't work. So you have to make sure that all devices between min and target level work correctly.

Comment: Regarding wanting to use the `.Light` themes in a platform-dependent way, you might be able to use `Theme.DeviceDefault.Light`.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a theme in your values/styles.xml and then in your values-v11/styles.xml override it with the Holo-version:

values/styles.xml:

```
 <style name="DialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></style>
```

values-v11/styles.xml:

```
 <style name="DialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar"></style>
```

Do it that way, and you'll have Holo themes on API 11+ devices and regular themes on the others.

Regards
Steffen Vangsgaard