# android: PreferenceActivity theme

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-theme

I am developing for older versions of Android and am using a `PreferenceActivity` (I know `PreferenceFragment` is the right approach going forward).

My `PreferenceActivity` is taking the theme of my application, but I want it to take whatever the general settings theme is. How do I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832114/how-to-use-device-default-theme-for-app Hope this helps, although I can't see preference activity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you want to use the android's default one?

So use something like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // API < 10
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme);
    // API > 11
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
    // API > 14
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

(or do the same in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file).

Comment: setTheme needs to be invoked before super.onCreate