# Making Android EditText look the same

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm creating a simple login activity and I am trying to make the edittext look the same on all devices. In Android Studio it looks the same on all APIs but on real devices it looks very different. What can I do to achieve they all look the same?

This is how it looks in Android Studio

[image: This is how it looks in Android Studio]

And this is how it look on a real device

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. I'm still learning Android development.

Comment: Don't trust emulators!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background of widgets are **API** level dependent.

Set this xml to your `EditText` background attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
<solid android:color="#4C000000"/>
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
             android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
             android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
             android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

This will have the same look and feel of your `EditText` on every API.

Comment: Thanks. I used your answer and added a bottom border to it and kinda simulated the way it is shown in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

It totaly depends on the way you use the emulator. The emulator, since the common AVD (used in Eclipse, or that kind of IDEs) until the Android Studio, will gonna use the default skin to show the widgets and components in the development environment.

You can install the manufacturer device skins to simulate your emulator as the original one. Look at that [description from the Samsung official website](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-GALAXY-S2-Skin-for-handset-emulation):

> The Emulator Skin is a simple way to test your Android application on a simulated GALAXY S2. The emulation does not simulate all features of an actual device, however. The emulation allow you to see how your application’s display scales to the GALAXY S2's screen.

It'd improve your testability in that case, but is also recommended to always test in the real device to get a better result.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it happens because you haven't specified Theme for your application. And according to the [documentation](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html)  android choses theme based on the following rules:

> If an app does not explicitly request a theme in its manifest, Android
>   4.0 will determine the default theme based on the app’s targetSdkVersion to maintain the app’s original expectations: For
>   values less than 11, @android:style/Theme; between 11 and 13
>   @android:style/Theme.Holo; and for 14 and higher
>   @android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.

You can find more details in the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832114/how-to-use-device-default-theme-for-app).

Comment: I have specified the theme to be android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar in my manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

In your drawable folder create edittext_style.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item><layer-list>
        <item><shape>
                <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#ffffff" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:type="linear" />

                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#CECFCE" />

                <corners android:radius="0dp" />

                <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="8dp" android:top="3dp" />
            </shape></item>
    </layer-list></item>
```

Define below code in style.xml,

```
    <!-- Edittext Style -->
<style name="edittext_style">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittext_style</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#DFFFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

And there you go, Just use color code as per your requirement,

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    style="@style/edittext_style"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```