# Android default theme

Tags: android, android-theme

I am making an Android application and am thinking about themes.

If I don't declare a theme for my Android application, what theme will be used?

Where I can find this information?

What is the criteria for use one and other?

I was thinking that, if I wanted to customize my application, I would have to extend a theme and customize the items I want.  What if it assumes one of them as the default?  How do I know what the default is?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832114/how-to-use-device-default-theme-for-app

Answer (score 22):

The default theme varies depending on the API level (to be consistent with the general UI).

On API < 10, the theme was a set of styles (as in the link below) known as `Theme`, above that API 10, the default theme was `Theme_Holo` and now, starting with API 21, the default theme has become `Theme.Material`.

- API < 10: see the [frameworks's code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) `Theme` or `Theme.AppCompat`
- 10 >= API < 21: read the [Styles and Themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) guide `Holo_Theme` or `Theme.AppCompat`
- API >= 21 [Using the Material Theme](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) guide `Theme.Material`

Most of those styles are available through the `android.support` libraries.

**PS:** AFAIK the light theme has always been the default one.

Comment: What if i want use Theme_Holo for all,including <10?

Comment: Then you need to look at something called "HoloEverywhere" which is kinda useless now that `AppCompat` is out...

Comment: @user1851366 To use Holo or even Material Themes on versions as low as 7 you should use android support library v7. You can use AppCompat (provides Material Design Action Bar etc.) and also layout elements like like CardView or RecyclerView. It is well covered on Android official website.

Answer (score 4):

It is best to define a default theme yourself instead of relying on android to pick the default theme. This is because different versions of android *may* have completely different default themes, and could mess up your layouts.

You can declare a theme for your application in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application android:theme="@style/MyTheme" .....>
```

Then in `res/values` folder, you edit/add a file `themes.xml` and add something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
         ... customize your theme here
    </style>
</resources>
```

You can edit the `parent` of your theme to anything you want...

You can also use `@android:style/Theme.Holo` directly in `AndroidManifest.xml` if you do not want *any* customization at all.

Use `Theme.AppCompat.Holo` if API version below 11

Answer (score 2):

The default theme for App is implement in [Resources.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java)!

```
    /**
 * Returns the most appropriate default theme for the specified target SDK version.
 * <ul>
 * <li>Below API 11: Gingerbread
 * <li>APIs 11 thru 14: Holo
 * <li>APIs 14 thru XX: Device default dark
 * <li>API XX and above: Device default light with dark action bar
 * </ul>
 *
 * @param curTheme The current theme, or 0 if not specified.
 * @param targetSdkVersion The target SDK version.
 * @return A theme resource identifier
 * @hide
 */
public static int selectDefaultTheme(int curTheme, int targetSdkVersion) {
    return selectSystemTheme(curTheme, targetSdkVersion,
            com.android.internal.R.style.Theme,
            com.android.internal.R.style.Theme_Holo,
            com.android.internal.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault,
            com.android.internal.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_DarkActionBar);
}
/** @hide */
public static int selectSystemTheme(int curTheme, int targetSdkVersion, int orig, int holo,
        int dark, int deviceDefault) {
    if (curTheme != 0) {
        return curTheme;
    }
    if (targetSdkVersion < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        return orig;
    }
    if (targetSdkVersion < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        return holo;
    }
    if (targetSdkVersion < Build.VERSION_CODES.CUR_DEVELOPMENT) {
        return dark;
    }
    return deviceDefault;
}
```

It varies depending on the API level, so you'd better to define your own AppTheme in AndroidManifest.xml to assure Theme in all API level devices.

Pls refer previous answer.