# Androids default theme

Tags: android

I coded my App without any styles.xml definition.
The only thing I changed is the background `android:background="#3b3b3b"` in every Activity. 
Now I want to go in deeper with theming. 
Which is the default theme any app is using with any definition?

Following this link [Android default theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277050/android-default-theme) it should be Holo. But when I define my style.xml like `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">` it looks very different to the scenario without defining any theme. I only want to change some thing to the default theme. For example the Actionbar Color is some kind of blue without defining a theme, with Holo its black.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There are currently 2, maybe 3 Themes (.Light etc not included)

- `Theme` is the default theme of Android up to 2.3, any changes in
  between included.
- `Theme.Holo` is the new default theme for Android Honeycomb and above.
- `Theme.DeviceDefault` is the theme that the device manufacturer set
  as default for devices running ICS and above. That theme might be
  custom (I don't know of any existing theme - so it's kind of 2 themes
  only). But these devices must include`Theme.Holo`.

You can also take a look here: [How to use device default theme for app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832114/how-to-use-device-default-theme-for-app)