# Android studio - How to use Samsung's TouchWiz skin in app theme?

Tags: java, android, themes, skin

I would like to replace my apps theme with samsung touchwiz theme for Samsung users (I am one). All I found on the internet is setting emulator skin. I don't want an emulator I have a Samsung device I want my app to look like Samsung's stock apps. Components are themed. Instead of stock Android components (like Checkbox etc.) I want my app to use Samsung's themed components. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what device default is for, check out this question for more information:

[How to use device default theme for app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832114/how-to-use-device-default-theme-for-app)

Comment: Crashes as it launches"

Comment: ok the I changed ActionbarActivity to Activity works great thanks :)