# getActionBar() returns null after updating from AppCompatActivity to Activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I switched from supporting Gingerbread, since Play no longer supports it. I can now stop using support classes, and move to real ones. Except getActionBar is null

- Android marshmallow
- My Theme includes ActionBar (`@Style.AppTheme`)
- extending `Activity`, not `ActionBarActivity` or `AppCompatActivity`
- tried `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);` before `setContentView`, and even before `super.onCreate`
- calling `getActionBar` in `onCreate` after `setContentView`

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <style name="mp_name">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="search_date">
        <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="search_details">
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

styles.xml (v11)

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

styles.xml (v14)

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

styles.xml (v21)

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: AppTheme extends which Theme?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867076/getactionbar-returns-null

Comment: You should keep using AppCompat. Even if you were API 21+ and could use the material themes, you'd still want to use it (there are changes even at API 23 that AppCompat takes care of for you).

Comment: use `AppCompatActivity`  and `getSupportActionBar()`

Comment: I checked all the solutions there, @Shailesh 

The whole point of switching to min sdk 14, is I no longer need to use AppCompat and supprotaction bar, i can use the real deal

Comment: @AnuragSingh AppTheme inherits from Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: Share your `style` xml code and java code which you are using to get `actionbar`.

Comment: OK, I put style code in the original question. The java code to get actionbar is irrelevent, I commented it out, and now the activity runs -- without an ActionBar.

Comment: Switching back to AppCompatActivity brought the actionbar back, but I want to use regular activities

Comment: Check this that how to use default theme from API 10 to API 21 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832114/how-to-use-device-default-theme-for-app

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried getSupportActionBar()? That worked for me when I had a similar issue.

You might also want to check one of the answers on this thread: 
[getActionBar returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031180/getactionbar-returns-null?rq=1)

Comment: i did not try `getSupportActionBar` since I am not using the support `Activity` class. Also i tried all those solutions, hence the list of things I did in the post

Answer (score 0):

Reason being `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>`. Remove this and try.
No need to use `Theme.AppCompat` since you are not inheriting `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: where is `<item name="windowActionBar">` to remove from?

Comment: It works when I switched back to AppCompatActivity, but I want to use regular activity class

Answer (score 0):

1. Check you manifest if u have added theme to you activity (if added then remove it).
2. Check if you have added correct theme to your Application

   ```
   android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   <activity
       android:name=".activity.SplashScreen"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```

Comment: i specifically said in the question that I am using `@Style.AppTheme`