# themed splash screen without setContentView

Tags: android, themes, splash-screen, android-theme

I added a splash screen to my app, without `setContentView` (to avoid unnecessary delays); but I can't seem to find how to change that splash screen depending on an user selected app theme.

I tried to use `setTheme` before `onCreate` on the corresponding activity, but it doesn't work. I also tried to use theme attributes (`?android:attr/colorPrimary`), but it doesn't work either.

I searched, but can't seem to find anything about changing the theme dynamically.

Here is how my activity is reference in the manifest :

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">

        ...

    </activity>
```

How my style is defined:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

And how my drawable is defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@mipmap/ic_beacon" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

How can I change the background color of the splash screen depending on the user selected theme ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use device default theme for app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832114/how-to-use-device-default-theme-for-app)

Comment: Can't you use viewpager concept and show different fragment for your splash screen using different theme

Comment: The question you linked to doesn't say how to change the theme programmatically, but how to change it depending on the version of android

Comment: I don't really see how I could use a `ViewPager` without using `setContentView`, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I tried using [activity aliases](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/01/16/preserve-your-launchers-use-activity-alias/), but I can't get it to work.